# C# MVC A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

In my website admin, I have an option to export incomplete orders to a CSV file. Clicking on export throws below exception.

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

Exception Details.

> Exception Details: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

The database is MySql and I am using entity framework to get the data. Below is the code.

```
DbContex db = new DbContex();
//Getting exception on below line
List<vwFullOrder> vwFullOrders = db.vwFullOrders.Where(x => x.order_status == false).OrderByDescending(o => o.created_date).ToList();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataRow dr = null;
dr = dt.NewRow();
dt.Columns.Add("SessionID");
dr["SessionID"] = "SessionID";
dt.Columns.Add("DateCreated");
dr["DateCreated"] = "created_date";
dt.Rows.Add(dr); //Header Row
 foreach (var c in vwFullOrders)
 {
    dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["SessionID"] = c.session_id;
    dr["DateCreated"] = c.created_date;
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
 }

 string csv = SharedUtils.GenerateCSV(dt);//Method to generate CSV string
 //Download the CSV file.
 Response.Clear();
 Response.Buffer = true;
 Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=incompleteorders.csv");
 Response.Charset = "";
 Response.ContentType = "application/text";
 Response.Output.Write(csv);
 Response.Flush();
 Response.End();
```

This code was working fine but now throwing an exception.
I have 65855 recorders in the order table. I have created a view vwFullOrder to get the data.

Please help! Thanks!

Comment: I think the issue in the connection string. Please check connection string. Debug the code and check vwFullOrders getting data or not...

Comment: @A.M.Patel Added the connection string. I didn't get the data because the exception is on vwFullOrders.

Comment: @SiddharthDoshi Please reconfirm your database name

Comment: @ReyanChougle Database name is cart_prod.

Comment: @SiddharthDoshi can you try this <add name="CSname" connectionString="metadata=res://*/entity.darwinCart.csdl|res://*/entity.darwinCart.ssdl|res://*/entity.darwinCart.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=dbstance.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com;initial catalog=cart_prod;user id=userID;password=password;persistsecurityinfo=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />

Comment: @A.M.Patel your connection string doesn't work it throws System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported exception.

Comment: @SiddharthDoshi your connectionstring has cart_prod&quot as database name.. Please correct this and try again

Comment: Can you replace keyword server to data source and then check

Comment: @ReyanChougle database name is correct as I am using the same connection string to log into my admin dashboard. The &quot; is for "

Comment: @A.M.Patel the connection string is working fine for my other database commands. There is no issue with the connection string.

Comment: Why don't you try to disable the timeout for your command. You can specify Command Timeout=0 in your connection string (the default is 30).

Comment: @Tayyab I have tried setting Command Timeout=0 but it didn't resolved issue.

Comment: Whats the execution time for retriving the data from the view vwFullOrders?

Comment: @Ardit it takes 4min 10sec to run the query.

Comment: @SiddharthDoshi try setting a breakpoint in the line when your running the query. Do you have your records List<vwFullOrder> vwFullOrders or at this point it goes on exception?

Comment: @Ardit No, I don't get the records it throws the exception at List<vwFullOrder> vwFullOrders.

Comment: @SiddharthDoshi Have you checked that the properties are mapped correctly form the view and the model? Try this before running the query `db.Database.CommandTimeout = 360;`

Comment: @Ardit setting `db.Database.CommandTimeout = 360;` worked but it is the temporary fix. The databases size will increase over the time and so the time to run the query will increase.

Comment: @SiddharthDoshi It's the query that takes too long, you should do a refactoring to improve performance sql view or think another way to collect the data.